# Forget to user .close() while using FileReader & BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm using the following code snippet to read a file line by line and write the same in another file. My input file contains roughly `13000` lines but it generates the output file with just `12000` lines only

```
public class FileReadWrite {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    FileReader input = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter printer = null;
try {
    input = new FileReader("input.txt");
    File output = new File("output.txt");
    br = new BufferedReader(input);
    printer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
    String s;
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
            printer.write(s);
            printer.newLine();
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.err.println("Exception occured"+e);
}
}
```

after adding this code snippet it works fine

```
finally{

            try
            {
                    input.close();
                    br.close();
                    printer.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
    }
```

any reasons for that?

Comment: If its Java, please edit and add that tag. Does "BufferedReader" ignore blank lines?

Comment: No it doen't ignore blank lines

Comment: does your final final contains the same end line character and does the encoding is the same ? you can check that with notepad++ for example

Comment: Why are you copying this line by line as text?  When you convert to/from text you are assuming your don't need an exact copy of the original which can be due to encoding issues or different newlines being used. Also it's much slower than copying using binary.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i don't think it as an encoding issue bcos it working fine after adding the finally block which i specified

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing a binary transfer which has a number of advantages

- you don't decode/encode your text so you don't have to worry about the encoding mangling your text
- you don't have to worry about matching the new line separators which could be `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`
- you don't need to copy to/from a buffer. All the copying is done in native code/memory.
- the code is shorter and much faster

The try-with-resource block closes the resources for you/

```
try (FileChannel from = new FileInputStream(fromFile).getChannel();
     FileChannel to = new FileOutputStream(toFile).getChannel()) {
    from.transferTo(0, from.size(), to);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to process the strings line by line thats why i choose this approach

Answer (score 0):

closing buffered (infact all) streams is important.

When you close a stream, buffered contents are flushed to disk - resulting all 13k records to written to file.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we work with File Input/Output in java. The Code uses important resources of system to read and write.
Due to this reason we must have to close all streams and after writing data into any file we must have to use method flush and close, otherwise all data may not be written.